# Prove or disprove this argument

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $L>0$ and let $\Omega$ be the set of all integrable functions from $[0,L]$ to $]0,+\infty[$.

For all $\varphi, \psi \in \Omega$ define $\left \langle \varphi,\psi \right \rangle:=\int_{0}^{L}\varphi(x)\psi(x)dx$.

Let $f,h\in \Omega$ such that $\left \langle f,h \right \rangle=\frac{1}{2}L^{2}$. Also, consider the set
$\omega(k):=\{g\in \Omega\colon \left \langle \textbf 1,g \right \rangle=1\wedge\left \langle h,g \right \rangle=k>0\}$,
where $\textbf 1\in \Omega$ is the function that maps everything to $1$. Note that $f$ or $h$ are not $\textbf 1$.

Is it true that for every $k\in]0,+\infty[$:

$\displaystyle \frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \omega(k)}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \omega(k)}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}$ is constant, that is, does there exist $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \omega(k)}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \omega(k)}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}=\alpha$.

Comment: what does "cte" means?

Comment: It means: Constant.

Comment: @Git Gud: I have just defined the inner product.

Comment: @Amir your mean is 'Constant value'??

Comment: @Software are dadash ;)

Comment: @Amir 'For a definite f  and an unknown g' what is your mean?

Comment: @Software for a determined f and an altering g.

Comment: @Amir $\huge\color{blue}{+}$ for your nice question ;)

Comment: Maximum taken over $g$?  Minimum taken over $g$? Constant means independent of what?

Comment: I've completly rewritten the question to make it more clear. Hopefully everything is intelligible now and the OP can confirm that I didn't alter the meaning of the question.

Comment: I think there might be a typo.  Since $\langle 1, \lambda g \rangle = \lambda \langle 1, g \rangle$ (for $\lambda \in ]0,+\infty[$), you can't have $\langle 1,g \rangle = 1$ for all $g \in \Omega$.

Comment: It should be "Let $\Omega$ be **a set of**" instead of "*the set of all*". That much is clear :)

Comment: @fedja I don't understand why you say 'a' is more clear than 'the'.  The article 'a' is indefinite while 'the' implies there's only one such set.

Comment: @AaronTikuisis Question mark missing and you should also make adjustments to the *there exists* bit.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. (i) It asks you to suppose something false. If you did that, then everything follows anyway. (ii) The conclusion is a triviality. Clearly, an expression containing no variables must be constant. (iii) The title asks to prove or disprove an *argument*, but the body of the question doesn't contain an argument (perhaps *statement* was intended).

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Thanks for your points. I think I have corrected the question as you have expected. Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what the OP meant was:

Set $\Omega_1 := \{g \in \Omega \mid \langle \textbf 1,g\rangle = 1\}$.
Then, is it true that $\displaystyle \frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}$ is constant, that is, that there exists $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \Omega}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \Omega}\left \langle f,g \right \rangle}=\alpha$?

In this case, the answer is no.
For example, let 
$$f_1(x) = 1$$ and
$$f_2(x) = \begin{cases} 1,\quad &x \in [0,1]; \\ 2,\quad &x \in ]1,2].\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f_1,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f_1,g \right \rangle}=1,$$
but note that $\max_{g \in \Omega_1} \langle f_2,g\rangle \geq \frac{\|f_2\|_2^2}{\|f_2\|_1} = \frac53$, and $\min_{g \in \Omega_1} \langle f_2,g\rangle \leq 1$, (using functions $g$ which are close to being $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ on $]1,2]$) so
$$\frac{\max \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f_2,g \right \rangle}{\min \limits_{\large g\in \Omega_1}\left \langle f_2,g \right \rangle}\geq \frac53 > 1.$$

Comment: $f$ is defined. $g$ is a variable! For a definite $f$, alter $g$ to find the max and min. Is it constant for every $g$?

Comment: @Aaron It should be 'that is, does there exist $\alpha \in \Bbb R\ldots$'. Same in the question, if you wanna correct it.